# GridFS: what it gives us

Tags: mongodb, replication, nosql

I'm reading "Seven Databases in Seven Weeks". Could you please explain me the text below:

> One downside of a distributed system can be the lack of a single
>   coherent filesystem. Say you operate a website where users can upload
>   images of themselves. If you run several web servers on several
>   different nodes, you must manually replicate the uploaded image to
>   each web server’s disk or create some alternative central system.
>   Mongo handles this scenario by its own distributed filesystem called
>   GridFS.

- Why do you need replicate manually uploaded images? Does they mean some of the servers will have linux and some of them Windows?
- Do all replicated data storages tend to implement own filesystem?

Comment: Revisiting. Something that slipped past me was the "Seven databases in 7 weeks": You can barely master one database in 7 weeks (there is a difference between knowledge and experience). Even something as simple as a KV store might take longer. Just wanted to ensure that a casual reader understands that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## On the need for data distribution and its intricacies

Let us dissect the example in a bit more detail. Say you have a web application where people can upload images. You fire up your server, save the images to the local machine in `/home/server/app/uploads`, the users use the application. So far, so good.

Now, your application becomes the next big thing, you have tens of thousands of concurrent users and your single server simply can not handle that load any more. Luckily, aside from the fact that you store the images in the local file system, you implemented the application in a way that you could easily put up another instance and distribute the load between them. But now here comes the problem: the second instance of your application would not have access to the images stored on the first instance – bad thing.

There are various ways to overcome that. Let us take [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) as an example. Now your second instance can access the images, and even store new ones, but that puts all the images on one machine, which sooner or later will run out of disk space.

Scaling storage capacity can easily become a *very* expensive part of an application. And this is where GridFS comes to help. It uses the rather easy means of MongoDB to distribute data across many machines, a process which is called [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/). Basically, it works like this: Instead of accessing the local filesystem, you access GridFS (and the contained files within) via the MongoDB database driver.

As for the OS: Usually, I would avoid mixing different OSes within a deployment, if at all possible. Nowadays, there is little to no reason for the average project to do so. I assume you are referring to the *"different nodes"* part of that text. This only refers to the fact that you have multiple machines involved. But they perfectly can run the same OS.

## Sharding vs. replication

> **Note** The following is *vastly* simplified, because going into details would well exceed the scope of one or more books.

The excerpt you quoted mixes two concepts a bit and is not clear enough on how GridFS works.

Lets first make the two involved concepts a bit more clear.
*Replication* is roughly comparable to a RAID1: The data is stored on two or more machines, and each machine holds all data.

*Sharding* (also known as "data partitioning") is roughly comparable to a RAID0: Each machine only holds a subset of the data, albeit you can access the whole data set (files in this case) transparently and the distributed storage system takes care of finding the data you requested (and decides where to store the data when you save a file)

Now, MongoDB allows you to have a mixed form, roughly comparable to RAID10: The data is distributed ("partitioned" or "sharded") between two or more shards, but each shard may (and almost always should) consist of a replica set, which is an uneven number of MongoDB instances which all hold the same data. This mixed form is called a *"sharded cluster with a replication factor of X"*, where X denotes the [non-hidden members per replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/).

The advantage of a sharded cluster is that there is no single point of failure any more:

- Depending on your replication factor, one or more replica set members can fail, and the cluster is still working
- There are servers which hold the metadata (which part of the data is stored on which shard, for example). Those are called [config servers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/). As of MongoDB version 3.0.x (iirc), they form a replica set themselves – not much of a problem if a node fails.
- You access a sharded cluster via a the [**`mongos`** sharded cluster query router](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) of which you usually have one per instance of your application (and most often on the same server as your application instance). But: most drivers can be given multiple mongos instances to connect to. So if one of those mongos instances fails, the driver will happily use the next one you configured.

Another advantage is that in case you need to add additional storage or have more IOPS than your current system can handle, you can add another shard: MongoDB will take care of distributing the existing data between the old shards and the new shard automagically. The details on how this is done are covered in the [introduction to Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) in the MongoDB docs.

The third advantage – and the one that has the most impact, imho – is that you can distribute (and replicate) data on relatively cheap commodity hardware, whereas most other technologies offering the benefits of GridFS on a sharded cluster require you to have specialized and expensive hardware.

A disadvantage is of course that this setup only is feasible if you have a lot of data, since many machines are necessary to set up a sharded cluster:

- At least 3 config servers
- At least a single shard, which should consist of a replica set. The minimal setup would be two data bearing nodes plus an [arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/)

But: in order to use GridFS in general, you do not even need a replica set ;).
To stay within our above example: Both instances of your application could well access the same MongoDB instance holding a GridFS.

### Do all replicated data storages tend to implement own filesystem?

Replicated? Not necessarily. There is [DRBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Replicated_Block_Device) for example, which could be described as "RAID1 over ethernet".

Assuming we have the same mixup of concepts here as we had above: Distributed *file systems* by their very definition implement a file system.

Comment: thanks you a lot for such a nice answer! I learned a lot about GridFS, and you answered my question. But I still have one question. Suppose you'are using MongoDB without GridFS. And you have two nodes `A` and `B` inside the first shard. If you will insert image to node `A` you *have to copy* it to node `B` manually with task/script. If you will insert a JSON to node `A` you *have not* to copy ot to node `B`. *What's the difference? Or where I'm wrong?*

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk You _are_ wrong. Replication, regardless wether we are talking of GridFS or plain BSON docs is automagically done within a replica set.

Comment: strange, that was said in quote I pasted from a book: `"you must manually replicate the uploaded image to each web server’s disk or create some alternative central system."`. Okay, not I got it - it replicated anycase with or without GridFS

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk That is when you do _not_ use MongoDb.

Answer (score 1):

In this case,IMHO, author was stating that each web server has own disk storage, not shared with others - having that - upload path could be /home/server/app/uploads and as it is part of server filesystem is not shared at all as a kind of security with service provider. To populate those we need to have a script/job which will sync data to other places behind the scenes.

This scenario could be a case to use GridFS with mongo.

How gridFS works:

> [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) divides the file into parts, or chunks [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), and stores each
>   chunk as a separate document. By default, GridFS uses a chunk size of
>   255 kB; that is, GridFS divides a file into chunks of 255 kB with the
>   exception of the last chunk. The last chunk is only as large as
>   necessary. Similarly, files that are no larger than the chunk size
>   only have a final chunk, using only as much space as needed plus some
>   additional metadata.

In reply to comment:
BSON is binary format, and mongo has special replication mechanism for replicating collection data (gridFS is a special set of 2 collections). It uses OpLog to send diffs toother servers in replica set. [More here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb)

Any comments welcome!

Comment: thanks for quick reply! It's still a little bit tangled for me. Correct me pls if I'm wrong. MongoDB stores all text data as BSON, but images are stored outside of database without any convertation/archiving, right? So, script/job is only needed for images/videos/audios but not for regular documents, right? How than MongoDB replicates regular BSON data?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Have a look at the [according docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/), as a full explanation exceeds the scope of SO.

Comment: @profesor79 so images can't be automatically replicate to  geographically distributed replica sets since MongoDb writes some kind of reference to them in OpLog instead the whole image, right? In the same way when you insert document `{ "name": "Alex", "age": "20" }` it can be replicated since all document is persisted in OpLog?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I think the book have covered main points of that doc. The question is - *why some data can be automatically replicated and some can not?*

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk documents aren't persisted in oplog. OpLog is used to sync data from master to other servers.

Comment: @profesor79 as I understand oplog is a diff file. Servers need only to download/update oplog to get sync among each other. Suppose you insert `{ "name": "Alex", "age": "20" }` to master. How it will be replicated through replica sets automatically?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk please see Markus comment.

Comment: @profesor79 I took a look at that docs, and all they said is `Secondary members copy the oplog from their sync from source and apply these operations in an asynchronous process.` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replication
Maybe to answer my question you should explain how secondaries apply oplog, and how that operation differs btw images and documents?